What is the etymology of "sip" (to seep) in Hakka?
There is a word in Hakka, [sip],

Meaning, just like English seep.
Sound, also just like English seep.

So where does it come from?
"滲" would seem to be the answer, but it is -m, not -p.
Example on https://elearning.hakka.gov.tw/ :

饒平 sib chudˋ【siab cudˋ】 華語 水湧出或滲出的樣子。

Yes, "cudˋ" is 出， but what (本子) is "sib/sip"?

Maybe 潗, 泄, or 洩. See https://kemdict.com/search?q=%E6%BD%97&m=prefix or https://kemdict.com/search?q=siab&m=prefix

Interesting. It seems the -p's and the -t's end up crossing over...
